# How to add list of float in python?

Tags: python

I'm making a program where the parameter "note" is a float but it needs to be added as a list. Here is a snippet of the error I got on `pytest`:

The expected result is

```
{'TransNum': [10, 15],
 'genre': 'H',
 'identifiant': 'ETUD031',
 'nom': 'Terry Gilliam'}
```

The actual result is

```
{'TransNum': [15],
 'genre': 'H',
 'identifiant': 'ETUD031',
 'nom': 'Terry Gilliam'}
```

And my code to understand the problem:

```
def ajout_note(dico_etudiant, matiere, note):
    liste_note = [note]
    dico_etudiant[matiere] = liste_note
    diconew = dico_etudiant
    return diconew
```

Thanks !

Comment: Please try asking this way: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

here you go

https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp

This outlines basics. Something you should read before asking this kind of a question which will most likely get closed.

Also you need to post code snippets, not images, and you ignored every rule about question asking.